# How to create a GUI-like text interface in C

Tags: c, unix, command-line-interface

I have seen a few programs that use simple GUI-like interfaces made out of text. A good example would be `links` (see screenshots below).

Are there any C libraries for creating this sort of thing out there? I would ideally like mouse support but that is not strictly necessary. Cross-platform is good but I really only need it for *nix-like systems (including mac). I don't have a great deal of experience with C but I know my way around it, coming from C++.

If libraries aren't available, how would one go about coding this kind of thing from scratch?

Screenshots of the kind of thing I want:
[image: Screenshot of links menubar]
[image: Screenshot of links address prompt]

EDIT: Yes, I know about `curses`/`ncurses`, but does anyone know of any good tutorials to make this kind of program with it?

Comment: This may be helpful - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: @CairnO. I was looking at the `ncurses(3X)` man page just as you posted this comment! Do you know of any good tutorials/guides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at CDK--
[project home page](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/cdk.html).

This is a set of widgets for Menus, pulldowns etc. wrapped around the basic ncurses library so your coding is at a much higher level and a lot of the intricacies and gotchas of ncurses are already dealt with.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Unfortunately, the only tutorial I can find is in french! Can you direct me to a good one?

Comment: Google "CDK and vexus" -- they are the original authors and may have some samples etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try ncurses - this is a library which with you may create such GUI environments under console.

Comment: I was looking at the `ncurses(3X)` man page just as you posted this. Very helpful, but I could benefit greatly from a tutorial if you know of a good one...

Comment: How about http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/ ? This is a basic tutorial for ncurses.

Comment: That's great - I'll probably start with CDK, so I've given that answer the tick, but this looks like a great next step once I'm comfortable with making TUI's! (I will upvote once I have enough reputation!)

Answer (score 0):

The best tutorial I know for curses is [Using C With Curses, Lex, and Yacc: Building a Window Shell for Unix System V, by Axel-Tobias Schreiner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139328645)

Comment: Thanks, but I hadn't anticipated buying a book!

Comment: I understand, but Amazon has used ones for $.01 + shipping. And it really is the best source for this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider ordering a copy!